# how does list x operates if(x % i) == 0

Tags: python

so i'm learning coding for a few weeks now and just got over something that i really cant explain by my self.

```
for word in ['ox', 'cat', 'lion', 'tiger', 'bobcat']:
    for i in range(2, 7):
        letters = len(word)
        if (letters % i) == 0:
            print(i, word)
```

when we define variable `letter = len(word)` this literally means `letter = 5` right? If it do so and we go over to the if condition it says: `(letter % i) == 0` for me what this means is when we start the second for-loop `(5 % 2) == 0 (1) == 0` I know thats actually not right cause `word` in that case is a variable and not a list. But if i set `letter` so the position of each word like `ox= len(0)` that doesn't makes sense to me either thats how i am thinking about this. unfortunately shell is has given me this

```
    2 ox
    3 cat
    2 lion
    4 lion
    5 tiger
    2 bobcat
    3 bobcat
    6 bobcat
```

I really can't figure out how this loop works but i really want to understand. I'ver tried several things but nothing worked in a sense of logic.

I hope you can help a beginner out :) P.S. sorry for my bad english haha

Comment: Indentations matter in Python. please fix

Comment: `%` is the modulo operator. Just search for 'python modulo operator'

Comment: @RedCricket He seems to understand that, he knows that `(5 % 2)` is `1`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `word` is a variable whose value is a string. So `len(word)` is the length of the string.

Comment: Try `for word in ['ox', 'cat', 'lion', 'tiger', 'bobcat']: print(word)` and you'll see what `word` is (hint: it's not the list).

Answer (score 0):

To start, `len(word)` is not necessarily 5, it's the length of the current word. So, first it is 2, then 3, then 4, then 5, then 6. You've made it so the program only prints when `(letters % i) == 0`. For the words of length 2, that only happens (in your range of 2 to 7) when `i == 2`. For words of length 3, this happens when `i == 3`. However, for words of length 4, this happens when `i == 2` and also `i == 4`. You can see this by looking at the values of i printed out.

Does that make sense? If you'd like me to clarify anything, just leave a comment :)

Comment: Alright, thanks. Really needed that clarification. Thank you :) 

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this resolved your question, you can mark the answer as accepted if you like :)